# Sharepoint permissions hide documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, custom-permission-level, sharepoint-permissions

I have a document library and I want to give access to client. I want to hide all documents by default including published documents except the few I share with them. If I upload new document it should not be visible to them by default until I share with them.

Which I have done by creating a custom permission level. They are able to open the documents page and are able to edit as is needed. But they do not have access to the main web page. No permissions I change allow them access to the site page.

I have "View Pages  -  View pages in a Web site." Check but they still cant view the page.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when write documents page - It is document library view page or page of a document? and what is the main web page? - It is main page of the web site?

Comment: Yes to both. The Documents pages is the Default Documents Library that gets setup with a Team site. The main web pages is the default landing page of that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by stop inheriting from parent on site pages, and gave the user group access to view the pages.

Comment: Great to hear that. In this case, please mark Your answer (this one) as accepted (green check mark) so the question will be closed and resolved.